# How to implement escaping

Tags: algorithm, escaping

PREAMBLE: I am not asking what is escaping and how to use it

Imagine you write your own sort of simple "scripting language" or rather, you just want to implement some magic words (variable). In a simple fashion (pseudo language):

```
var a = "hello";
var b = "world";
var string = "this is a string with variable $a and $b";
string = string.replace("$a", a).replace("$b", b);
```

Looks quite simple.

Now imagine, someone would put "$b" into `a` what would happen is that $a gets replaced with "$b" and "world" is twice in a string.

Also, what if someone wanted to put literally "$a" in a text (not being variable). Most languages offer some sort of escaping, I would like to escape this, for example using backslash. Therefore "\$a" would turn into "$a" in final string.

What is most simple way to implement this (properly).

I can imagine many ways how to accomplish this, but they are mostly pretty complex and inefficient. So instead of reinventing the wheel I would like to see a proper solution.

No libraries and language neutral please.

Comment: Is that *really* all you want to support?

Comment: Way too broad... If it would be problem in any particular language you'd match all replacement tokens at once (i.e. with `$[a-z]` regular expression) and replace all at once...

Comment: I don't think there is anything broad on this, every language that implements escaping needs to solve this issue, so there needs to exist some universal solution. I would prefer avoiding regexes if possible.

Comment: You have asked two different questions: (1) What happens if the replacement string contains a 'replace" token, and (2) How do you produce a 'replace' token in the output. You should break this into two separate postings.

Comment: @A.I.Breveleri OP did not *ask* two questions. Implementing escaping *correctly* requires those two *requirements.*

Answer (score 2):

You don't "first replace all the `$a`", for precisely the reason you describe. Instead, you scan left to right loking for any replacement pattern. In you simple language where all variables are single letters, a " replacement pattern" might simply be a <kbd>$</kbd> followed by a character. Once you find the pattern, you then figure out which variable to replace it with. After the replacement, you carry on with the rest of the template string. So everything is just scanned once.

Regular expression libraries and scanner generators are handy, here. Many languages (python, perl, lua, ecmascript, ...) have a search-and-replace library function whose search argument is a regex and whose replacement argument is a function; the function is called with the matched substring and returns the replacement string. That will cover many simple syntaxes.

For more complicated syntaxes, (f)lex-like scanner generators can easily create transducers, allowing for an even more general implementation of the same idea. (It's more general because it is not limited to using a single regex.)

None of that has to do with escaping because you don't need to escape to avoid multiple replacements. You simply need to avoid rescanning. However, explicit escapes can be handled in *precisely the same way*; the explicit escape syntax(es) are just added to the set of possible replacement patterns, along with appropriate actions to generate the replacement value. (For example, replace <kbd>\</kbd> followed by a special character with just that character.)